# Interactive: region beginning/end as markers

Tags: interactive, marker

When I need a function to operate on a region I do, for example:

```
(defun myfunction (B E)
 (interactive "r")
 (let ((b (make-marker))
       (e (make-marker)))
   (set-marker b B)
   (set-marker e E)

   ;; DO SOMETHING THAT CHANGES THE BUFFER, THEN

   (comment-region b e)))
```

Is there a simpler way to have B and E as markers?

Comment: I seldom really need markers. If I really need a marker then usually only at one end. When I use markers I often do `(let ((m (make-marker))) (unwind-protect (progn (set-marker m pos) ...) (set-marker m nil)))` to avoid the dangling marker living on until the next `garbage-collect`. When you don't care about the dangling marker you can do `(let ((m (set-marker (make-marker) pos))) ...)`. One sees that quite often in libraries. In some cases `(save-restriction (narrow-to-region b e) ...)` is an alternative to markers.

Comment: Not caring about a dangling marker seems like a bad habit.

Comment: @phils I use this kind of markers management in my LaTeX typesetting scripts and I can assure you that it is very usefull.

Comment: I suspect the only way to make this simpler is by making a helper macro (like, `with-markers`) and reusing it.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi I just meant that in general you should set markers to `nil` when you are done with them, otherwise they can continue to consume processing resources.

Comment: @phils I thought that let-binding them was sufficient. But I'm not so good in best coding practices. I'll study the question (sooner or later).

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi,  `buffer-has-markers-at` can be used to confirm that the marker still exists after the `let`-bound variable goes out of scope.

Comment: @wasamasa (I am afraid that) your proposal is the only way to make markers simple and clean at the same time. There exists something like that: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6l116o/withmarkers_macro/. By the way: for me the pain was never large enough to write a special macro.

Comment: @phils If I understand you say that, after running my scripts, I have all those markers active in my buffer? A function to remove all markers in the buffer would be the solution?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi, you need to use `(set-marker MARKER nil)` while you still have a handle on it (e.g. before the `let`-binding goes out of scope).  That said, I did just confirm that the markers *do* get garbage-collected in that `let`-bound scenario (at some later point after they are out of scope); so although it's still best-practice to explicitly set them to `nil` when you are finished with them, they don't stick around forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case given don't see a necessity for a marker:

```
(defun my-comment-region (start end)
  (interactive "*r")
  (comment-region start end))
```

A marker is needed, if the start/end positions are going to change during execution and should follow that change:

```
(defun my-change-of-region (start end)
  (interactive "*r")
  (let ((end (copy-marker end)))
    (delete-region start end)
    ;; start and end should be equal now
    (message "%s" start)
    (message "%s" end)))
```

As `start` doesn't change in example above, its marker would be useless. Only the end-marker has effect.

Comment: It's exactly what I needed. Indeed start/end positions are both going to change during execution (LaTeX typesetting). I didn't know about the "copy-marker" function.